# Pagination with sub field in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation

I want to query from mongodb sub field and can pagination for it. Thankss!

```
  {
    "_id": "616d274c655e0000ee005f32",
    "subscription": [
      {
        "account_admin": "5fe5707399cc690013a159b2"
      },
      {
        "account_admin": "61b9bac72258040012e218d5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "616fe5786b1b0000a9007a95",
    "subscription": [
      {
        "account_admin": "5fe5707399cc690013a159b2"
      },
      {
        "account_admin": "61b9bac72258040012e218d5"
      },
      {
        "account_admin": "5df739c4dfb7940013388e5f"
      },
      {
        "account_admin": "61b9b21daaa08000115f4da3"
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

How to find mongodb by field account_admin: "61b9bac72258040012e218d5"
to data below (pagination if can)

====>

```
 [ 
  {
   "account_admin": "61b9bac72258040012e218d5"
  },
  {
   "account_admin": "61b9bac72258040012e218d5"
  }
 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting sub-fields are can be done with '[dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)'. Pagination is simply using `query.limit()` and `query.skip()`.

I've not tested the code but this should work.

```
const query = Model.find({ "subscription.account_admin": "61b9bac72258040012e218d5" });

query.limit(documentsPerPage);
query.skip(documentsPerPage * currentPageNumber);

const results = await query.exec();
```